# I am not able to find in computer where this php v5.3.28 is installed

Tags: php, xampp

If i go to localhost/xampp i see `php version 5.5.9`;
If i check from windows command line `php-v i get 5.3.28`.
If i check from windows command line `c:\xampp\php\php -v i get 5.5.9`.

I am not able to find in computer where this `php v5.3.28` is installed. It is also not on the PATH variable. It is default php version. How to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `php -i > yourfile.txt`. You will find a lot of information there. Look for "extension_dir"; it will probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: I use the following command from windows cmd: "c:\xampp\htdocs> php -i c:\xampp\htdocs\phpifile.txt" . The problem is that information is not outputed to file phpifile. I try to search for this file in all C disk. WIndows do not find it. Could you please also help this step in searching php directory.

Comment: You are missing the '>' character after -i: php -i > "c:\xampp\htdocs\phpifile.txt".

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, for easy question. The answer is to use windows folders search and search for string "php". AS results many files are outputed. Part of them belongs to xampp installation. One folder named "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express" contains this 5.3.28 version of php.